# Get internal byte array from ByteArrayInputStream

Tags: java

I want to get the internal byte array from ByteArrayInputStream. I don't want to extends that class or write it into another byte array. Is there a utility class that help me do that?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Extend `ByteArrayInputStream`, then you have access to the `protected` fields. It's the way to do it. Constructors are provided to take the byte array from an argument.

However, you may find the decorator pattern more helpful.

Answer (score 24):

You can not get access to the same byte array, but you can easily copy the contents of the stream:

```
public byte[] read(ByteArrayInputStream bais) {
     byte[] array = new byte[bais.available()];
     bais.read(array);

     return array;
}
```

Comment: I don't want to do this bc i don't want to have another copy of my byte array.

Comment: While this code should work in practice because of our internal knowledge of the operation of `java.io.ByteArrayInputStream`, in theory it doesn't abide by the contract of InputStream, which -- to be correct -- needs you to check the return value of the `read` method to detect a partial read.

Comment: Correct. I am only doing this because I "know" the method is passed a ByteArrayInputStream.

Comment: I don't want to create another copy of my byte array. Memory concerns in here.

Answer (score 4):

With the library Apache COmmons IO (http://commons.apache.org/io/) you can use the `IOUtils.toByteArray(java.io.InputStream input)`

Edit : ok, I didn't understood the question... no copy...
Maybe something like :

```
byte[] buf = new byte[n];
ByteArrayInputStream input = new ByteArrayInputStream(buf);
```

will allow you to keep a reference to the buffer used by the input stream

Comment: It is IOUtils (capital U, I believe)

Answer (score 1):

No. Extending the class is the only way (well, that and using reflection to bypass the field visibility, which absolutely NOT recommended).

Comment: why you are not recommending reflection?

Comment: @Sean: because it's slow and error-prone (and won't work at all if the code runs in a sandbox).

Comment: Can you explain more about "it's slow"? Running in a sandbox you mean with security settings?

Comment: @Sean: accessing fields throgh reflection is at least an order of magnitude slower than doing it directly. And yes, you need to use setAccessible() to access a protected field through reflection, and that can be prohibited by a SecurityManager.

Answer (score 0):

The internal field is protected, so extending would be easy. If you *really* don't want to, reflection may be another way. This is not a great solution since it relies on internal workings of ByteArrayInputStream (such as knowing the field is called `buf`). You have been warned.

```
ByteArrayInputStream bis = ...
Field f = ByteArrayInputStream.class.getDeclaredField("buf");
f.setAccessible(true);
byte[] buf = (byte[])f.get(bis);
```

Answer (score -3):

No, access to the internal array is not provided except through the toByteArray() method, which makes a copy.

Comment: Where did you find `toByteArray` in `ByteArrayInputStream`?

Comment: toByteArray() only exists in ByteArrayOutputStream

Comment: He confused ByteArrayOutputStream with ByteArrayInputStream.