# Convert Contents Of A ByteArrayInputStream To String

Tags: java, string, bytearrayoutputstream, bytearrayinputstream

I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5778658/java-converting-from-outputstream-to-inputstream) but I am not following.  I have seen [this](http://www.coderanch.com/t/278987/java-io/java/convert-Bytearray-input-stream-String) but have not seen a proper example of converting a `ByteArrayInputStream` to `String` using a `ByteArrayOutputStream`.

To retrieve the contents of a `ByteArrayInputStream` as a `String`, is using a `ByteArrayOutputstream` recommended or is there a more preferable way?

I was considering [this example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4315848/get-internal-byte-array-from-bytearrayinputstream) and extend `ByteArrayInputStream` and utilize a [Decorator](http://javapapers.com/design-patterns/decorator-pattern/) to increase functionality at run time.  Any interest in this being a better solution to employing a `ByteArrayOutputStream`?

Comment: You probably want an `InputStreamReader`, as described in the second link that you gave.  A `ByteArrayOutputStream` won't convert the bytes to characters.

Comment: Do you really have a ByteArrayInputStream (which implies you have a byte[]) or do you just have an InputStream?

Comment: @BrettOkken I really have a ByteArrayInputStream whose constructor is passed an array of bytes (varying size)

Comment: @DavidWallace There was a reply to the post in the second link using an InputstreamReader: `The problem with this is that it reads only up to and including the first line separator. It assumes that the string you're looking for does not contain any line separators. Often that's true, but if not, this won't really work.` Why I am not proceeding with that example.

Comment: But you can just keep reading from it until it's empty.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

A `ByteArrayOutputStream` can read from any `InputStream` and at the end yield a `byte[]`.

However with a `ByteArrayInputStream` it is simpler:

```
int n = in.available();
byte[] bytes = new byte[n];
in.read(bytes, 0, n);
String s = new String(bytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8); // Or any encoding.
```

For a `ByteArrayInputStream` `available()` yields the total number of bytes.

---

***Addendum 2021-11-16***

Since java 9 you can use the shorter [readAllBytes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes--).

```
byte[] bytes = in.readAllBytes();
```

---

***Answer to comment: using ByteArrayOutputStream***

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
byte[] buf = new byte[8192];
for (;;) {
    int nread = in.read(buf, 0, buf.length);
    if (nread <= 0) {
        break;
    }
    baos.write(buf, 0, nread);
}
in.close();
baos.close();
byte[] bytes = baos.toByteArray();
```

Here in may be any InputStream.

---

Since java 10 there also is a `ByteArrayOutputStream#toString(Charset)`.

```
String s = baos.toString(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Comment: How would a ByteArrayOutputStream read from a ByteArrayInputStream?

Comment: I have extended the answer. In principle one loops reading from the `InputStream` and writing to the `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Out of tradition the I/O buffer has a ritual size being a power of 2.

Comment: Agree with power of 2 size; I like that and thank you.

Comment: From the javadoc of the [InputStream.available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#available--) function: _It is never correct to use the return value of this method to allocate a buffer intended to hold all data in this stream._

Comment: @nucatus true, I did not state that `in` is that `ByteArrayInputStream`. For [ByteArrayInputStream#available()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/io/ByteArrayInputStream.html#available()) one may.

Answer (score 29):

Why nobody mentioned `org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils`?

```
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils;

String result = IOUtils.toString(in, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Just one line of code.

Comment: I added the two required `import` statements so that not everyone has to search for them. Sorry... it's not just one line of code anymore ;)

Comment: Sorry but I think this answer is not correct. Because if your input is ByteArrayInputStream you will get compile error. The correct input for this function is InputStream

Answer (score 10):

Java 9+ solution:

```
new String(inputStream.readAllBytes(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `Scanner` and pass to it's constructor the `ByteArrayInputStream` then read the data from your Scanner , check this example :

```
ByteArrayInputStream arrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(new byte[] { 65, 80 });
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(arrayInputStream);
scanner.useDelimiter("\\Z");//To read all scanner content in one String
String data = "";
if (scanner.hasNext())
    data = scanner.next();
System.out.println(data);
```

Comment: If I have `XML` or `HTML` doc, will I be able read it without limitations?

Comment: Yes, there is  no limitation .

Answer (score 1):

Use Base64 encoding

Assuming you got your ByteArrayOutputStream :

```
ByteArrayOutputStream baos =...
String s = new String(Base64.Encoder.encode(baos.toByteArray()));
```

See http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Base64.Encoder.html

Comment: Nice solution.  But, I would need to first connect my ByteArrayInputStream into my ByteArrayOutputStream.  How is that accomplished?

Comment: It's important to say that the Base64.Encoder was released in the Java 8. :)

Comment: It should be String s = new String(Base64.getEncoder().encode(baos.toByteArray()));    thanks though.

Comment: As @SiddharthGharge said the encoder creation is wrong. Also question is about InputStream, not OutputStream.