# SoapUI to get attachment from response in Groovy

Tags: groovy, soapui, bytearrayinputstream

I tried to use following code to get attachment from reponse as text in `Groovy`.

```
def testStep = testRunner.testCase.getTestStepByName("getData")
def response = testStep.testRequest.response
def ins =  response.attachments[0].inputStream
log.info(ins);
```

It contains some binary information too, so it is not fully human readable, but got following in output:

> java.io.ByteArrayInputStream@5eca74

Comment: You need to convert to string first. Here's an SO link on [Converting Contents Of A ByteArrayInputStream To String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24059266/convert-contents-of-a-bytearrayinputstream-to-string)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is easy to simply encode it to base64 and store it as a property value.

```
def ins =  response.attachments[0].inputStream
String encoded = ins.bytes.encodeBase64().toString()
```